# Using Sexpr{} within \SweaveInput{}

Tags: r, sweave

I have this 2 lines of code which I run with R Sweave function.

```
\SweaveInput{samples.rnw}
\SweaveInput{\Sexpr{args$samples}}
```

The first line leads to the inclusion of the content of the corresponding file, while the second just causes evaluation of the Sexpr{} term but nothing else.
What I want is both: first let evaluate the Sexpr{} term and afterwards do the inclusion of the respective file content.

How do solve this ?
Thanks

Comment: running the output of Sweave again with Sweave would do the trick. Are there more elegant solutions ?

Answer (score 3):

If you use the [`knitr` package](http://yihui.name/knitr), the solution would be simply

```
<<child='samples.rnw'>>=
<<child=args$samples>>=
@
```

Sweave is much weaker than `knitr` in terms of programmability. For example, `knitr` allows the chunk options to be any valid R expressions, which is the reason why we can write `child=args$samples` here; `knitr` will evaluate the chunk options just like function arguments.

BTW, the `child` option is equivalent to `\SweaveInput{}`, but I strongly discourage the use of the pseudo LaTeX command. For more about Sweave vs `knitr`, see http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/sweave/